# How can I get the setState function in React Context and set it as the default value in createContext?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following super-basic react context:

```
    import { FC, createContext, useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction, PropsWithChildren } from "react"
    
    export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>({currentUser:null, setCurrentUser:null})
    
    type UserContextType = {
        currentUser: UserType | null
        setCurrentUser: Dispatch<SetStateAction<UserType | null>> | null
    }
    
    export type UserType = {
        username: string
    } | null
    
    export const UserProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
        const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<UserType>({ username: "John" })
    
        return <UserContext.Provider value={{ currentUser, setCurrentUser }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>

    }
```

The problem is that by defining currentUser and setCurrentUser as 'null', every time I want to call any of those values, I need to use the optional chaining operator (or other check to ensure it's not null).

For example, I uset this context here:

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { UserContext } from "../../contexts/UserContext"
import { Button, Typography } from "@mui/material"

export default function TestPage() {
    const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useContext(UserContext)
    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={() => setCurrentUser?.({ username: "Doe" })}>Change Name</Button>
            <Typography>{currentUser?.username}</Typography>
        </>
    )
}
```

Now, I think the optional chaining operator is fantastic... but I don't want to have to use it EVERY time I ask for the username.

How can I get the actual `setCurrentUser` function before the UserProvider has called the useState hook (and creating the `setCurrentUser` setState function), so I can have a default `setCurrentUser` function and it's never set to `null`?

Are there better ways to deal with this that I'm just completely missing?

(to be clear, this code works fine...the problem is with typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the actual setCurrentUser function before the UserProvider has called the useState hook (and creating the setCurrentUser setState function), so I can have a default setCurrentUser function and it's never set to null?

That specific idea is not possible. `setCurrentUser`  does not exist yet, so you cannot pass it into `createContext` to be the default value. Instead, here's some suggestions.

Before we start though, note that most of the time when a react app uses context, the intention is that the default value will never be used. The default only gets returned if there is no `<UserContext.Provider>` higher up the component tree, and that's only going to happen if you havn't finished writing/debugging your code. So the following suggestions are all going to assume that you want TestPage to always get the value from UserProvider, and never the default.

With that in mind, one option is to provide a default value that matches the type you want, but has dummy values:

```
type UserContextType = {
  currentUser: UserType | null
  setCurrentUser: Dispatch<SetStateAction<UserType | null>>
}

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>({
  currentUser: null, 
  setCurrentUser: () => {
    console.error('oops, the default got used. Fix your bug!');
  }
  // or just:
  // setCurrentUser: () => {}
})
```

---

For complicated context objects, filling in all these dummy values can be combersome. In that case, you could use a type assertion to shut typescript up. This is easy to write, but it does lose some typesafety, since you're telling typescript not to check your work.

```
export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>(
  // This object obviously doesn't match the type, but we're assuming it will never be used
  {} as UserContextType
)
```

---

And then we get to the option that i prefer: When you create the context, allow it to be either the type you want or undefined. But then when you use it, throw an error if it's undefined.

I prefer this approach because it gives you rigorous typechecking, while not requiring you to create a dummy value, and also lets you add in some logging to help you during development.

```
export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType | undefined>(undefined)

// ... 

export function useContextThrowUndefined<T>(
  context: Context<T | undefined>
): T {
  const value = useContext(context);
  if (value === undefined) {
    const name = context.displayName ?? "Unnamed";
    throw new Error(
      `${name} context consumer was used outside of a context provider.
To fix this, make sure the provider is always higher up the component tree than the consumer.`
    );
  }
  return value;
}

// ...

export default function TestPage() {
  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useContextThrowUndefined(UserContext)
  return (
      <>
          <Button onClick={() => setCurrentUser({ username: "Doe" })}>Change Name</Button>
          <Typography>{currentUser.username}</Typography>
      </>
  )
}
```

If typing `useContextThrowUndefined(UserContext)` is too long, feel free to extract it to a hook, such as:

```
const useUser = () => useContextThrowUndefined(UserContext);

// ...
export default function TestPage() {
  const { currentUser, setCurrentUser } = useUser();
```